# Edit client JS while debugging Node in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

Trying out VS Code on Mac OSX and it would be nice to be able to edit my client JS whilst debugging my Node code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at this time, but you can ask for it on [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Feature request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7769226-change-files-while-debugging